# pass image to other view controller in collection view didSelectItemAt

Tags: swift3

I want to implement a `collection view` for images in an `array` and when I will select the image in collection view cell it should take me to other `view controller` with an `image view` in it and should show the enlarged image of the selected on.

**What should be the code written for this in did select Item so that the selected image will be displayed in the other view controller?**

Answer (score 1):

After you have created a `DetailViewController` with an `imageView` (with the frame you prefer) and a variable called for example `var selectedImage: String?`, in your collectionView delegate function `didSelectItemAt` you have to instantiate your DetailViewController and before presenting it you can set its selected image var.

**Example:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedImage: String = imagesArray[indexPath.row]

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let detailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your identifier") as? DetailViewController
    detailVC?.selectedImage = selectedImage
    //present or push your detailViewController
}
```

Then in your `DetailViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let image = selectedImage {
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error in 4th line saying uiimage cant be converted to string

Comment: @TejalOhara Your images Array is an array of string? If this is true change the selectedImage var with: `var selectedImage: String?` You have to create a var of the same type of the objects you have in your images array. I have edited my answer.

Comment: the error is gone but image doent appear on next detail disclosure view

Comment: what will we do in that view to display the image in it what code to write there I have created outlet of image view and var seectImage : String?

Comment: Ok good, now, your images array contains the name of the images or the url?

Comment: I m adding a name of an Image

Comment: var images = ["DSC_0058 (3).JPG","DSC_0290 (2).jpg","DSC_0093.JPG","DSC_0108.JPG","19702231_1890551934517515_2895202307633607057_n.jpg","19665420_1889557577950284_3896443903905921832_n.jpg","17861935_1851337305105645_3838305929233325340_n.jpg","17498917_1844420709130638_7576367038118729740_n.jpg","117342743_1842947945944581_5085533580006641829_n.jpg"]

Comment: It gives error while unrapping a value at line no 2 in detailview controller

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedImage = images[indexPath.row]
        let detailVC = ViewControllerImagegallery() // if you use storyboard check how to init a ViewController from storyboard
        detailVC.selectedImage = selectedImage
        //present or push your detailViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }

Comment: @TejalOhara have you solved it? If not check if your outlet is connected.

Comment: the outlet is also created should I post u all the code in comment

Comment: @TejalOhara I have understood, you are using storyboard so you have to change your DetailViewController init. I have updated my answer, check it.